# How to hide vertex colors in Texture Paint?

Tags: texture-painting, vertex-colors

I am currently trying to paint a texture onto a character model.  However, I cannot actually see what I am doing because one of the vertex color layers is being overlaid on top of the texture, causing it to appear solid black in most areas.

Are there any way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: Are you sure it is from *Vertex Colors* and not because you do not have *Shadless* enabled?

Comment: As I said, "solid black in most areas".  The areas where it is not solid black correspond to the likewise areas in the vertex colors.  Further, toggling shadeless doesn't do anything other than make stuff full-bright, and the areas that were black stay black.

Comment: Alright, just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a Vertex Color layer that is solid white and keep that one activated when you are not doing any Vertex Painting.

It does waste a layer and definitely counts as a work-around but it's the only way I know of to do this and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are painting on an image texture mapped to UV, you might get around this by using GLSL if you are using Blender Internal materials, and disabling the effect of the vertex color in the shader until you are ready to use it. If you are using Cycles, then using vertex color through the Attribute node is easy to disconnect from diffuse input until needed.

All this is using the Texture draw mode, but with Cycles you are supposed to be able to use the Material draw mode to get a semi-GLSL experience.

Answer (score 1):

A commit was made a few days ago by Antony Riakiotakis, one of the blender developers, to fix this:

[rB711a5c79d8c4: Don't use vertex colors in textured mesh display during texpaint](https://developer.blender.org/rB711a5c79d8c4105dc0ccf771b79d66c79ee3c570)

To quote Antony:

> Don't use vertex colors in textured mesh display during texpaint.
>
> Wasn't that irritating?

Because of the timing of this commit I imagine the fix will appear in 2.75.